# VBScript get process id by process name or program executable name

Tags: windows, vbscript, process, executable, pid

I need to do exactly as I asked in the question for any program that I have just started from my VBScript.

I am starting the System Properties program from VBscript as below:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe"
WScript.Sleep 1000
```

Now I want to get the process id of `SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe` program, how can I do that ?

I would like to do this purely by VBScript without mix coding as much as possible.

Comment: (First google result)[https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21638733/How-do-you-get-the-PID-of-a-process-started-by-WshShell-Run.html

Comment: Just check the answer with the program I am opening first, it is not working, maybe it works with calculator, it is tiny program, I want process id of System Properties

Answer (score 1):

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process where name='Calculator.exe'")
'msgbox colitems
For Each objItem in colItems
    msgbox objItem.name & " " & objItem.ProcessID & " " & objItem.CommandLine
    If objItem.name = "Calculator.exe" then objItem.terminate
Next
```

This uses WMI to query for Calculator.exe and then terminates it.

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct and thanks for that, but I have the main problem, can we discuss in the chat ?

Comment: I want to appactivate `SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe` process by id and then I want to press ENTER by code itself and this is not working, can you help ?

Comment: Perhaps you should use `Set WshEnv = WshShell.Environment("PROCESS")
` and `WshEnv("TestVar") = "Windows Script Host"` to change for current process. Edit the registry if you want to make it permanent.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to to start process and get processID with **`WshShell`** Object:

```
Dim sh : Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set Rtn = sh.Exec("SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe")     'write the full path of application 
WScript.Sleep 1000                                 'stop script 1 sec waiting run the App
MsgBox "my App PID  :   "  & Rtn.ProcessID                            'Process ID for App
```

OR   use **`WMI`** to start process and get the processID

```
set process = GetObject("winmgmts:Win32_Process")
process.Create "SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe",null,null,processid
MsgBox "my App PID  :   "  & Processid
```